# induction proof for the amount of edges in a boolean lattice graph

Tags: graph-theory

We define the boolean lattice graph $BL_n$ with $n\ge 1$ as the graph with vertex set the power set of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and two vertices are adjacent iff their symmetric difference is exactly one.

I can show that the amount of edges of $BL_n=n2^{n-1}$, by altering each set by one and diving by two to account for the double counts. However, I would like to prove it via induction and struggle to see the induction step.

For $n=1$ the statement is clear. Assuming it is true for $BL_{n-1}$ we would like to prove it for $BL_n$.

I've tried to construct $BL_n$ from $BL_{n-1}$, where we add $2^{n-1}$ vertices and now need to find the amount of edges we add. Clearly, I can take each vertex from $BL_{n-1}$ and add the new element $n$. By this I've created all the connection between $BL_{n-1}$ and $BL_n$. However, there are missing edges, with vertices both only in $BL_{n}$. Formally, I would like to show

$$ n2^{n-1} = (n-1)2^{n-2}+x$$

where $x$ are the added edges. Solving for $x$, leads to
$$x=2^{n-2}(n+1)$$

I can't see how this is derived geometrically. Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$BL_{n+1}$ will consist of two copies of $BL_n$, one whose sets do not contain $n+1$ and one whose sets do contain $n+1$. 
There are $ 2^{n}$ edges  between these two copies. So there are 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \times n 2^{n-1} + 2^n = (n+1) 2^n
\end{eqnarray*}
edges in $BL_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as the one-dimensional skeleton of a hypercube $H_n$.  We get from dimension $n$ to dimension $n+1$ by putting one copy of $H_n$ in the $x_{n+1}=0$ hyperplane, one copy in the $x_{n+1}=1$ hyperplane, and adding an edge joining corresponding vertices of the two copies.